# Searching tables in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, user-controls

I have hacked together a drag and drop search as part of a UI experiment I am doing.

So far I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/craigie2204/pJDPQ/20/

When you drag the weather button it will only display rain. My Question(s?) is:

Can this be an additive process for instance. User drops Weather which display rain but then also drops day Tuesday. So Can the table display all the search results where it is raining on Tuesday? If so could you provide any references on how this can be achieved.

Also I have tried to set a time interval on the function which checks to see if the droppable div has class. This is so that if a user removes the draggable item then the string associated with this div is removed from the search. This didn't seem to work would any body be able to point me in the direction of how this could be done (if it can).

As always if you want to mess about with the JSfiddle be my guest.

PS. as said above the code is kind of scrappy as I just had together bits of code I find on the net to get the desired UX so sorry in advance.

Thanks guys,

Craig

```
$(function () {
var $result = $('.result');
$('.drag').draggable({

});
$('.drop').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        outputResult(ui.draggable);
    }
});


setInterval (outputResult(elm), 100);

function outputResult(elm) {
    if ($(elm).hasClass('oweatherType')) {

        searchTable("rain");

    } else if ($(elm).hasClass('oday')) {
        searchTable("Tuesday");
    } else if ($(elm).hasClass('olocation')) {
                searchTable("Scotland");
    }
}

});

function searchTable(weatherSelect) {
var table = $('#tblData');
table.find('tr').each(function (index, row) {
    var allCells = $(row).find('td');
    if (allCells.length > 0) {
        var found = false;
        allCells.each(function (index, td) {
            var regExp = new RegExp(weatherSelect, 'i');
            if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (found === true) $(row).show();
        else $(row).hide();
    }
});
}
```